# Pythons, Selenium and the XPATH of a new window

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

How does one grab an element by xapth when that element doesn't show up until after you use the .click() method AND that element is located in a portion of the JavaScript, in something called BODY_BLOCK_JQUERY_REFLOW.

I'm trying to access this part of the html.

```
<div class="ui_radio item" data-value="it" data-tracker="Italian">
    <input id="filters_detail_language_filterLang_it" type="radio" name="filters_detail_language_filterLang_1" value="it" onchange="widgetEvCall('handlers.updateFilter', event, this);">
 <label for="filters_detail_language_filterLang_it" class="label">Italian <span class="count">(11)</span>
 </label>
</div>
```

I can access the prior languages 1 - 3, but when I go for the 4th language (and more), I cant parse the xpaths because it it shows up as an overlay.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import os
import time
from lxml import html


chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--windows-size=1080*720")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-proxy-server")

headers = {'User-Agent': ''}
proxies = {"http": ''}
chrome_driver = os.getcwd() + "/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, executable_path=chrome_driver)
driver.get("https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attraction_Review-g60776-d117416-Reviews-Colorado_National_Monument-Fruita_Colorado.html")

# here we click on the more languages element
driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="taplc_detail_filters_ar_responsive_0"]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[5]""").click()

html_thing = driver.page_source

innerHTML = driver.execute_script("return document.body.innerHTML")
parser = html.fromstring(html_thing)


#T hese XPATHS work since they are part of the DOM on intial load
XPATH_LANG1 = '//*[@id="taplc_detail_filters_ar_responsive_0"]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/label/text()'
XPATH_LANG_COUNT1 = '//*[@id="taplc_detail_filters_ar_responsive_0"]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/label/span//text()'
XPATH_LANG2 = '//*[@id="taplc_detail_filters_ar_responsive_0"]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/label/text()'
XPATH_LANG_COUNT2 = '//*[@id="taplc_detail_filters_ar_responsive_0"]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/label/span//text()'
XPATH_LANG3 = '//*[@id="taplc_detail_filters_ar_responsive_0"]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/label/text()'
XPATH_LANG_COUNT3 = '//*[@id="taplc_detail_filters_ar_responsive_0"]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/label/span//text()'


# Unfortunately, these XPATHS dont work. Im assuming because they are in this JQUERY thing.
XPATH_LANG4 = """//*[@id="BODY_BLOCK_JQUERY_REFLOW"]/div[12]/div[2]/div/div[5]/label/text()"""

print(XPATH_LANG4, 'this is lang 4')

raw_lang1 = parser.xpath(XPATH_LANG1)
print(raw_lang1)
raw_lang_count1 = parser.xpath(XPATH_LANG_COUNT1)
print(raw_lang_count1)
raw_lang2 = parser.xpath(XPATH_LANG2)
print(raw_lang2)
raw_lang_count2 = parser.xpath(XPATH_LANG_COUNT2)
print(raw_lang_count2)
raw_lang3 = parser.xpath(XPATH_LANG3)
print(raw_lang3)
raw_lang_count3 = parser.xpath(XPATH_LANG_COUNT3)
print(raw_lang_count3)
raw_lang4 = parser.xpath(XPATH_LANG4)
if not raw_lang4:
    print(raw_lang4, '<--------------- THIS IS EMPTY')
else:
    print(raw_lang4, 'It actually showed up')

driver.close()
driver.quit()
```

Ive tried using `driver.find_element_by_xpath(""""""), Ive tried parsers, and everything else I can think of.

The issue seems to be that while the language, in this case "Italian" (the 4th language in the overlay) is in the page source, the XPATH cant see it. This is a challenge because the page uses dynamic id's or none at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to click "More languages" button and wait until required options appeared in modal window:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait

driver.get('https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attraction_Review-g60776-d117416-Reviews-Colorado_National_Monument-Fruita_Colorado.html')
wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//span[.="More languages"]'))).click()
languages = [lang.text for lang in wait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="more-options"]//label')))][1:]

print(languages)

['English (1,463)', 'German (34)', 'French (24)', 'Italian (11)', 'Dutch (9)', 'Chinese (Sim.) (8)', 'Danish (5)', 'Portuguese (4)', 'Spanish (4)', 'Japanese (2)', 'Russian (2)', 'Polish (1)']
```

Comment: You have no idea how long that took me to do.

Comment: Looking over your answer, @Andersson, it is very concise, I like your approach. I have a lot to learn from that comment.